# What happens if polymorph ends while under disguise self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, illusion, stacking

Premise: I am under the effects of disguise self to look like a human and I am in fact, an elf. I then cast polymorph on myself to turn into a T-rex and then take enough damage to make me lose concentration on polymorph, would I appear to be an elf or human after the spell drops? What if the spell was dropped due to the polymorphed T-rex running out of health?

Comment: Related: "[As a wildshaped druid, I’m getting polymorphed. What happens when the polymorph ends, do I revert to wildshape form or to normal form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180470)"

Comment: Also related: "[Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133379)"

Comment: @Medix2 That second one is a strong candidate for marking as a dupe

Comment: sweet, thanks! that definitely didn't pop up with my  search

Answer (score -4):

Only your DM knows for sure, how magic works in their world, so the best answer is probably "try to find out". However, based on the spell description, I would say the Disguise Self should fail after the Polymorph:

> You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs.

As a T-Rex you don't have the same arrangement of limbs, so you are no longer eligible target to be affected by the Disguise Self spell effect.